# How to find Radius of convergence for this power series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given nth term of power series is    $4^n{x^{n^2}}$

tried ratio and root test but coudnt get to solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the power test

$$\left|{4^n x^{n^2}}\right|^{1/n}=4|x|^n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\ell(=0)<1\iff |x|<1$$
so the radius of  convergence is $R=1$.

Comment: can you please elaborate . i coudnt get it

Comment: The geometric sequence $|x|^n$ is convergent to a limit $\ell<1$ if and only if $|x|<1$

Comment: why x^n coudnt be infinity as n goes to infinity having infinite radius of convergence

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Finding_the_radius_of_convergence) how we find the radius of convergence.